# How do we know that God exists?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology

Simple enough question, and very much related to the topic.

According to traditional Jewish sources, on what basis should people believe that there's a God?

Comment: shoosh, if what you're actually seeking is sourced bases for belief in a specific quality of God (e.g. that he created the world or that he's omniscient) rather than his mere existence, then you might clarify that in the question before it gets more answers irrelevant to your main concern. (To be honest, I don't know how one can argue for God's existence unless you define "God" as, e.g., the creator or omniscient; and in that case what he's really arguing for is the existence of a creator or an omniscient being. So I guess I'm asking you to clarify, in your question, what you mean by "God".)

Comment: http://www.divineinformation.com/featured-videos/torah-and-science-2/

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYLHxcqJmoM

Comment: There are no absolute proofs (else there would be no _bechira_ [free will]), but there are some very strong arguments ....read [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Permission-To-Believe-Approaches-Existence/dp/0944070558) for more info

Comment: @Shokhet of course, if someone actually wanted a book discussing proofs of god, he should be directed to J. H. Sobel's Logic and Theism, but that's not really what we're trying to accomplish here, is it... But where did you get this idea that there wouldn't be free will if there was an absolute proof?

Comment: @Matt I don't recall specific sources; if you want I can start looking. It's certainly an idea that's been given over in many shiurim I've heard. .....actually, come to think of it, I think it may be in the intro to Lawrence Kelemen's book that I linked to; I'll check there first.

Comment: @Shokhet I think the source may be Avi Ezri Hil. Teshuva 5:5 but saying that goes against almost all of the rishonim, doesn't it? (At least rasag, rambam, the Chovos Halevavos, and the chinuch,  and if you had no rishonim supporting, that's quite a team you're going up against)

Comment: Are you looking for 'Jewish sources' specifically? Many "non-Jewish" sources actually contribute really well to this question...

Comment: Personally I believe that there must be a beginning, or better said a source from which all came forth, for me that's G-d. The answer to what came first the chicken or the egg, for me is G-d.

Comment: The title asks how we know that God exists, while the body of the question asks why we should believe that God exists. Those are potentially two very different things, and you should clarify which one you are asking.

Comment: Very poorly phrased. What do you mean by we? We humans, we Jews, we philosophers, we Rambam? I'm so frustrated to see that so many people took the bait.

Comment: @al berko Is there a difference? Proof is proof, irrespective of the audience and perspective.

Comment: I believe that you can know HaShem is there just by asking for proof, there will be proof given to you, whether it be through TV or a human being, if you keep your eyes open you will see your proof.

Comment: Statistically, it's virtually impossible for the universe with all of its components to have come forth as a matter of an accident. I've read about it in one of Rabbi Avigdor Miller's question and answer books. Can't remember which but it was something to the effect of "100 Questions and Answers..." I would search Amazon for it but my web filter don't let

Comment: Even one of the greatest minds gifted in numbers, Elon Musk (his colossal bank account can attest to that), had to resort to a bizarre explanation that we're living in a computer simulation in order to explain how complex the universe is. Note he doesn't accept any of the other secular explanations.

Answer (score 42):

How does a Chasid know that G-d exists?  He has Emunah.

How does a Litvak (a.k.a. Yeshivish Jew) know that G-d exists?

The [Rambam says so](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hamitsvot/ase1-2.htm), and the Raavad doesn't argue.  :o)

It may have been formulated as a joke, but it is a serious answer. We know that G-d exists because our sages have transmitted this fact. We can also experience G-d's Providence in our lives on a continuous basis, but that's a beneficial side-effect of knowing, not how we know. – user1095 Feb 1 '12 at 11:46

Comment: Should this be a comment?

Comment: It may have been formulated as a joke, but it is a serious answer.  We know that G-d exists because our sages have transmitted this fact.  We can also experience G-d's Providence in our lives on a continuous basis, but that's a beneficial side-effect of knowing, not how we know.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure. :)

Comment: I agree that it could exist nicely as a comment as well - except that I actually do list a source, which IMHO upgrades it to answer status.

Comment: @Will Maybe you should edit in some of the explanation you gave down here.

Comment: I feel God's providence over my life despite not knowing, but my strong belief seems to be adequate. Lucky me.

Comment: Why does the punchline to a joke have almost 30 upvotes?

Comment: @mevaqesh it actually has 31 upvotes.  But 6 sensible people have downvoted.

Comment: Just because the Raavad doesn't comment, doesn't mean he agree. This is obvious from many cases, even if some Achronim have assumed otherwise

Comment: This should be counted as spam.

Comment: -1 IMO this reflects poorly on Judaism, that the top-voted answer to arguably the biggest question is a joke

Comment: @sabbahillel Is "It may have been formulated as a joke, but it is a serious answer. We know that G-d exists because our sages have transmitted this fact" a quote from the poster?

Comment: @mevaqesh Yes, that is why I included the signature of the user and the date when I copied the comment (from him) up into the answer. It should have been part of the answer to begin with because the OP added the comment saying that was his intent.

Answer (score 32):

Assuming we all exist, think, know and interact with our actual surroundings etc.

### The Ontological Proof

The first class of Divine Proof is the Ontological proof. It goes basically like this:

`God as a concept is perfect.`

`Perfect things must have the quality of existing, else they wouldn't be perfect.`

`Hence, God exists.`

#### Problems

This doesn't really convince anyone of anything.

#### Possible Solutions

[Many philosophers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof#The_proof) have spent a lot of time tweaking this proof, but in the end I don't think anyone else really cares about it.

### The Cosmological Proof

The second class of Divine Proof is the Cosmological proof. First pioneered by Aristotle and taken up by [the](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1101.htm) [Rambam](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/maimonides/#GodViaNeg), it goes something like this:

`Everything that moves was moved by something else.`

`There cannot be an infinite regress of events.`

`Hence, there exists a Prime Mover and we call Him God.`

#### Problems

First off, you could just say that there *can* be an infinite regress of events.

Secondly, in the current proof what can God tell you to do? Move? Not so powerful...

#### Possible Solutions

To avoid the second problem, some have changed "move" to other powers and given those to God.

Alternatively, some focus on the fundamental nature of the proof which is that there exists a being external to the general rules of science. They will argue something like this:

`Morality* is eternally true independent of circumstances.`

`Hence, there exists some entity outside of the natural world and we call it God.`

(*Replace `Morality` with `Rationality` or some other fundamentally True concept as you please.)

This doesn't really get exactly the God we want, but it is better if you assume Morality/Rationality/etc. *is* eternally True independent of circumstances.

### The Teleological Proof

This is the most commonly given of the three Divine Proofs by organizations such as [Aish HaTorah](http://www.aish.com/sp/ph/48917862.html) and other (especially Charedi) organizations. It goes something like [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13765/759):

`[Some aspect of the world] is very complex.`

`Hence, it must be designed as such by a Higher Being whom we call God.`

#### Problems

It might not be. Everyone agrees this is not a strict proof. [BTW this is why people are so opposed to Darwin, not the textual issues from Genesis 1]

#### Possible Solutions

Err.. Find something REALLY REALLY complex.

### Summary

There is no strict philosophical proof for God; however, there is no strict proof against the existence of God either. You need to evaluate the evidence and BELIEVE.

Sources: Philosophy classes and personal research on the subject.

Comment: Nice exposition. You could improve this by citing sources that make or discuss these arguments (e.g. a particular place in the Rambam or a particular page on the Aish website)

Comment: +1. I like this a lot, even if the problems with the cosmological proof aren't themselves very convincing.

Comment: Downvote...? And thanks @msh210 for the formatting.

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks, but the first proof you mention doesn't cite any Jewish sources....

Comment: @msh210 I'm not aware of any Jews who utilize an Ontological proof of the existance of God. But I thought it was worth throwing out there anyway. If you know of any please edit them it.

Comment: As far as I remember the Ontological proof is a very Christian influenced thing.

Comment: @avi And Aristotle was a pagan. I don't know why it matters if the origin was Christian. If it's true it is perfectly applicable to Judaism as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA The concept of perfection behind the proof is in direct contradiction with many midrashim and some kabalistic ideas. It leads to very confused understandings. Aristotle had the Rambam to tweek his ideas and make them Jewish. I'm not aware of anyone who did that with St Ansalem's position.

Comment: @SethJ, Ralbag favored the teleological proof. First prove the world is created, then existence of God follows when defined as the Creator. [Link](http://books.google.com/books?id=zLxBQrY6inEC&lpg=PP1&dq=routledge%20jewish%20philosophy&pg=PA385#v=onepage&q=routledge%20jewish%20philosophy&f=false).

Comment: @DoubleAA, Only Jewish philosopher I know of that accepted the ontological argument is Moses Mendelssohn. Not sure if you want to use him as a source, though.

Comment: @avi I don't see what's wrong with perfection at least as a starting point to some supernatural being. None of these proofs are proving the exact god that we know as God. It's all just a start. You still need Judaism to teach you about God. Proofs for that are a separate question, I think.

Comment: @jake I concur with your research. I see no reason to edit in Mendelssohn unless the community continues to pressure for a 'Jewish' source. I think it's fine as it is now in the abstract.

Comment: Another commentless downvote? Anyone want to claim it?

Comment: The ontological proof: Is bad explained... For example, the perfect triangle. Does not exist. Decartes explain this proof more clearly

Comment: @juanora I gave a link to the most thorough treatment I know of (Gödel's) but I maintain that my listed problem is applicable anyway. We can get more technical about the modal logic involved, but I don't really think it matters here.

Comment: 4 commentless downvotes. That's got to be a record.

Comment: The question asks specifically for Jewish-sourced answers. Could you please [edit] into your answer a Jewish source for the ontological proof you outline? (The other proofs are cited already.)

Comment: in the cosmological proof, "There cannot be an infinite regress of events" is NOT correct. the point is that an infinite regress of non-eternal causes cannot account for the existence of something in the present, EVEN if it extends infinitely. illustration: if we see a chicken in the present, we cannot say it came from an egg, and that egg came from a chicken, etc, endlessly with the same repetitive argument. because, if there isn't "something" that existed eternally, then nothing would exist in the present.

Comment: @ray You continue bringing this chicken/egg analogy in some sort of infinite _pro_-gression as if it is supposed to make sense. If the chickens and eggs extend infinitely back, then there is no need for anything to exist eternally, in order for the current presence of a chicken to be justified.

Comment: 7 commentless downvotes?

Comment: Sorry for the many comment-less downvotes, but I majored in philosophy and cannot help be somewhat upset by what seems to me oversimplifications (and therefore misrepresentations) of complex and subtle issues (I don't want to nitpick on every line here). Additionally, the questioner specifically asked "According to traditional Jewish sources etc.", and your only Jewish philosopher is Rambam, whose own version of the cosmological argument is not stated here. (Sorry)

Comment: You say everyone agrees that the teleological proof is not a proof, an easily refutable assertion. Also, why no Jewish reference (e.g. the Chovos Halevavos amongst others has a pretty nice version). Speaking of which, his version is a good example of why it is a proof - unless you think there is also no proof (to the online reader) that you composed this answer as opposed to a group of hyperactive gibbons...

Comment: @loewian Can you prove the latter claim to me?

Comment: @DoubleAA That you're not a group of hyperactive gibbons? Statistically speaking the odds are not significant by any criterion used in science. More so the case with more sophisticated systems such as the universe.

Comment: @loewian "Statistically speaking the odds are not significant by any criterion used in science." Ok. So what? BTW how do you know that? Rational belief and logical truth are different. While the former may be epistemically viable, the latter is the sense I used "proof" in, keeping with the previous categories of "proof". The latter is also the only sense which is epistemically coercive. I think my description of the teleological "proof" is actually more than sufficient. Any early record of it pales in comparison to options brought by modern science anyhow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21602/discussion-between-loewian-and-double-aa).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1505/

Comment: @Loewian the chovot halevavot clearly divides the chapters. While in the first chapter he try to prove Gd existence,  in the gate of the verification he writes ideas for analyzing daily events and show how we can see Gd in everything. The Teleological proof is well described.

Comment: @DoubleAA from where do you extract the Cosmological proof of Aristotle? And, from what I understand of your description, I think that even Rambam disagree with this proof

Comment: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/18/6876.htm

Comment: wwhy do u think the Rambam adopted Aristotle? CAn you quote the palce of Rambam where thats implied?

Comment: @user8832 is gone, but here's one such place in case anyone still wants to know https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.17.2?ven=Guide_for_the_Perplexed,_English_Translation,_Friedlander_(1903)

Comment: Regarding the answer's description of the teleological proof: I believe this is incorrect. The teleological proof focuses on existence itself, rather than _movement_. Meaning "this finite thing must have come from somewhere, and an infinite regression of causes is impossible". Both the cosmological proof and the teleological one rely on the impossibility of an infinite regression. This type of proof was almost exclusively used by Jewish thinkers before the Rambam, and can be found in some form in Emunot U'De'ot, Kuzari and Cheviot Halevavot.

Comment: Furthermore: for those who claim above that the ontological proof is not used by Jewish thinkers, I urge you to read this article, which discusses this question: https://www.torahmusings.com/2019/11/the-ontological-arguments/

Comment: Further regarding the ontological argument: I must note that the ontological argument can indeed be found in Sefer HaIkarim,  מאמר א׳ פרק כג ד׳׳ה האחת, in which he argues that it is a mandatory belief that God can and did create the universe from absolute nothingness, even though it's not an "indispensable principle" (i.e. the rest of the religion would stay intact if we removed that idea.) Never the less, it is a mandatory belief, since to claim that God cannot create _ex nihilo_ would be to deny his perfection, which we have already taken as a given.

Comment: One last sally: the ספר העיקרים again makes an ontological type argument in מאמר ד פרק לה to explain why תחיית המתים is not a belief in God doing the logically impossible (like making a square whose hypotenuse is twice it’s sides): being that you can imagine it, to say that God cannot do it would be confining God. 
I don’t see that this is an argument that he will do it, but that he can. Does it follow from the ontological argument that since God can do it, he will? I’m not sure.

Answer (score 32):

To my knowledge, the only "argument" for the existence of God given in the Torah itself is that He directly revealed Himself to us at Sinai:

> Deut. 4:35 "Unto thee it was shown, that thou mightest know that the LORD, He is God; there is none else beside Him."
>
> Deut. 5:4, "The LORD spoke with you face to face in the mount out of the midst of the fire."

In other words, direct experience does not require philosophical proof.

Rabbi Jacob Emden expanded this argument into our own time, saying that, "When I consider these wonders [of the survival of the Jews in exile], they appear greater to me than all the miracles and wonders that God did for our ancestors in Egypt, and in the wilderness, and in the land of Israel."

All philosophical arguments for the existence of God made in traditional sources are only intended to reinforce this basic experiential knowledge that is the heritage of the Jewish people. While these arguments can serve to shore up our beliefs against challenges, many sources see these arguments as helping us acheive a more personal, immediate connection to God.

The most common such arguments found in Jewish works are:

1. The Argument from Design - Many aspects of the natural world appear to have been been designed with intelligence and intent.
2. The Cosmological or "First Cause" Argument - What set the world moving? Where did it come from?
3. The famous "Kuzari" argument (which is also found in the writings of R' Saadia Gaon and Maimonides), that the Sinai revelation was a historical event witnessed by the entire nation. (This argument is basically just an extension of the Biblical "argument" that is intended to enable us to rely with confidence on our historical tradition.)

In my personal opinion, the various philosophical arguments for the existence of God are mainly useful for countering Hume's arguments against miracles. Briefly stated, he argues that no testimony of a miracle should be believed unless the falsehood of the testimony would be more improbable than the miracle itself. It follows, therefore, that one's ability to accept the testimony of the Jewish people's historical experience of miracles has an inverse relationship with the degree to which you think miracles are improbable.

All of the classical arguments for the existence of God are, fundamentally, arguments that we can perceive an element of the supernatural in the natural world itself. Thus, each such argument makes the possibility of miracles more plausible. At some point, it becomes more likely that Sinai Revelation really occurred than that it was made up (which, per the Kuzari argument, is very unlikely). Once you reach that point, then you have the Sinai Revelation to rely on for everything else.

Comment: I think everyone was agreeing that you need Sinai and a Mesorah to teach you _about_ God. We are just discussing why one would believe He exists.

Comment: But if you were actually at the Sinai Revelation with your friend, would it make sense for him to then turn to you and say, "Wow! But we still need to prove that he exists." Sinai didn't just teach us about God, it also demonstrated His reality. Our problem is connecting ourselves with that experience.

Comment: Yes, but we weren't there (at least physically or whatever). So for us we prove things in order. First you have to prove God exists, then prove what you can about him. Using philosophical proofs is not as you say a side point. They are very much a kiyum in the Rambam's mitzva "leida sheyesh eloaH". They aren't just a way to get to the Sinai argument. They are inherently valuable for this purpose. Again, you still need to go prove other things about God. But in terms of his existence, philosophical proofs are just as good if not better.

Comment: I think really what you are saying is that buying into Sinai from the get-go is killing two birds with one stone. But that doesn't detract from taking things in steps.

Comment: So, a Jew who was present at Sinai and "met God personally", so to speak, would still need to "prove" God exists or his knowledge of God is lacking? That might fly with the Greeks, but I don't believe you will find support for it in Jewish sources. While medieval authorities, starting with R' Saadia Gaon, argued that philosophical proofs are a fulfillment of the mitzva of "yedias Hashem", they are only necessary because we lack direct knowledge.

Comment: While this is a strong Jewish "proof" it is clearly not the only one, since the Jewish people knew about Gd before Har Sinai.

Comment: Rambam (Hil. Yesodei HaTorah 8:1) writes that prior to Sinai, the Jews only had an unreliable certainty ("נאמנות שיש אחריה הרהור ומחשבה"). This was ever after the miracles of the ten plagues and the splitting of the Yam Suf.

Comment: @LazerA No! I said that someone who was at Sinai kills two birds with one stone, meaning they know of God's existence _and_ know about him. They don't need philosophical proofs. We on the other hand can take it in steps. First prove God's existence, then prove things about him.

Comment: Ok. That makes perfect sense. But, if we can establish the reality of the experience, then we have accomplished the same thing in principle, although we are missing the immediacy of the actual experience.

Comment: The mitzva of "yedias Hashem" is not just to know intellectually, but also to internalize the knowledge into your personality (וידעת היום והשבת אל לבבך). This is where the philosophical proofs come in, according to many sources (e.g. Shelah HaKadosh).

Comment: @LazerA Fine. I just felt that your answer seemed to treat philosophical proofs as a 'bedieved' way to do this nowadays.

Comment: I don't think they are b'di'eved (although R' Yehuda Halevi did), but I do think that many of us tend to focus on the philosophical proofs that happened to appeal to non-Jewish philosophers, and to neglect the uniquely Jewish arguments. Islamic and Christian philosophers generally make little use of the argument from the historical experience of the Jews (you'll find it mentioned briefly in some Christian works), mainly because it has implications that are problematic for them.

Comment: Where is this idea from Yakov Emden found?

Comment: @user6591 In Sulam Beis El, printed at the beginning of his Siddur, in the first section of חווק ב'. You can read the full quote in my blog post http://shesileizeisim.blogspot.com/2012/01/why-study-jewish-history-part-3.html

Answer (score 13):

Rabbi Hirsch says a "proof is in the pudding" type of argument, namely if you keep the mitzvos it will become clear to you through your experiences that you are involved in something higher.  It need not be explained - you will feel it, if you are keeping the mitzvos properly.  This experience is an experience of G-dliness, and is the best "proof" of His existence.

This is quoted in Dayan Grunfeld's intro to Horeb.

Comment: I dont like this answer, since it presupposes the belief in God. Muslims have told me the same thing: "you must read the whole Quran and practice it, and then you will SEE how it is supirior Godliness beyond anything which you can imagine"...

Answer (score 12):

I'm a terrible one for sources, however as far as I am aware there are four ways in which Judaism knows that Gd exists.

- **The first method is** brought in the midrashim regarding Abraham.  There are two stories that I know of regarding how Avraham knew that G-d existed.

  1. [Story](http://www.drungar.com/poems/2011/3/21/burning-up-inside-bira-doleket.html) [1](http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/2008/11/burning-house-reading-of-bereishit.html): (Thank you  @Monica Cellio)
     Abraham was walking along the way and saw a building that either (had a light in it's window, or was on fire), Avraham looked at the building and said, "Can that house have no master?, surely there is a master of the world."
     I have seen the midrash explained in two ways based on how you translate the line. Either, a building with a light on must have someone who lives in, and so with our world, life exists, so someone must have created it. Or, a house would only be on fire if someone owns it and an enemy wished to destroy it. Since there is evil in this world, and there is constant entropy, the fact that things get "built" means there is a creator. In modern language you might describe this as entropy vs evolution. However as with all midrashim, it could be undertood differently by each person.
  2. [Story 2](http://www.azamra.org/Earth/mount-03.html):
     Abraham was sitting in the sun, when suddenly a cloud blocked the Sun. The Cloud must be stronger than the sun, then a wind came, and the wind moved the cloud, so wind is stronger than clouds, then the wind came to a mountain and was blocked, so a mountain is stronger than wind, then a river was seen carving through the mountain, so water must be stronger than mountains, then the sun dried up the water, so the sun must be stronger than water... This cycle lead Abraham to believe that there must be a force outside of the cycles of nature which is strongest of them all, and runs it all, and that force is Gd.
     In modern language you might say, "That which breathes life into the equations." However as with all midrashim, it could be undertood differently by each person.

** Edit: It seems that the original midrash talks about man being better than spirit because of a wordplay, so I'm not sure where I heard this version from, but the basic concept is the same.

- **The second method** in which we know G-d exists, is in the fulfillment of prophecies and being able to see the hand of G-d in history. This is first mentioned in the Torah when G-d describes himself as the [Lord Your G-d who took you out of Egypt](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0326.htm).  This was a common way for the Rabbis of the Talmudic and Gaonic period to relate to G-d, [most notably the book the Kuzari](http://www.tsel.org/torah/kuzari/eindex.html) written by Yehuda HaLevi. Various prophecies have come true over the centuries, the latest of them being the return of the Jewish people to the land of Israel.
- **The third method** in which we know G-d exists is Rambam's principle of knowledge and the methods of books such as [Derech Hashem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derech_Hashem) which aim to prove G-d logically as either the first cause of all things, or show G-d as a necessity in some other logical manner.  This method became popular in the middle ages, and has only grown since then. This method has become the most popular over the centuries, to the point that now most Jewish understandings and proofs of Gd are no different from any other theistic philosophy.
- **The fourth method** of knowing that G-d exists is through [personal experience](http://hisbodidus.ilovetorah.com/) and prayer, where a person feels a close relationship with his creator. This is most common in circles influenced by the Hassiduth movement from the 18th century.

Comment: As with DoubleAA's answer, citations of specific sources would make this answer more valuable.

Comment: If someone wants to find the location of those midrashim, or a link to derech hashem, or a quote from rav Nachman regarding a personal relationship with Hashem, I will be in your eternal gratittude.

Comment: 1a = Teleological. 1b = Cosmological. 2 = Teleological. 3 = Cosmological. 4 = My Summary :)

Comment: @DoubleAA 1a and 2 are not really Teleological. Though 3 certainly covers your entire answer.  1 and 2 are unique ways of looking at the question, which only make sense from certain perspectives.  1 only makes sense in a  "comparative religion" sort of mentality, and 2. Only makes sense from a Jewish perspective.

Comment: The midrash about the burning house is from B'reishit Rabbah 39 -- *bira doleket* is a useful search term.

Comment: You're right about 1a. It's more cosmological (creator instead of causer and patterning the entire world after one apparent creation/causation namely the house). But 2 is definitely teleological. You are noticing that event happened (the results of an early statement being correct) deciding it is too improbable to have happened by chance and therefore there must be some Higher Being controlling it. That's teleological.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Anything missing sources now?

Comment: @DoubleAA Chance is the not the alternative to 2. The Alternative to 2, is that the prophecies don't come true. I.e it's a false statement /prophecy.  The idea that it's either Cause A or Chance only exists later on in history/philosophy.  Here it's either a real prophet or a fake prophet.  Completely different mindset. A self fulfilling prophecy isn't even a HavaMina :)

Comment: @avi, not that I can see, although some could possibly be a little more precise than pointing to an entire work. But this answer is certainly valuable as it is now; thanks!

Comment: Story 2 reminds me of Baba Batra 10B:  - He also used to say: Ten strong things have been created in the world. The rock is hard, but the iron
cleaves it. The iron is hard, but the fire softens it. The fire is hard, but the water quenches it. The water is strong,
but the clouds bear it. The clouds are strong, but the wind scatters them. The wind is strong, but the body bears it.
The body is strong, but fear crushes it. Fear is strong, but wine banishes it...

Comment: ...Wine is strong, but sleep works it off. 
Death is stronger than all, and Tzedakah saves from death, as it is written: (Proverbs 10:2) “And Tzedakah saves
from death.”

Comment: I knew the *birah doleket* source because I had a memorable class around it, which I wrote up here: http://cellio.livejournal.com/584351.html.  (If this comment is inappropriate 'll delete it; I'm trying to share what I learned, not plug my blog.)

Comment: My answer was basically a big ad for #4.

Comment: I finally found the source for the second story. In your link, R' Avraham Greenbaum calls it a Midrash — whoever said that originally made the story harder to find, although I can understand why: it's actually from Qur'an, Chapter 6, Sūrat l-Anʿām (The Cattle). https://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=6&verse=78
That being said, Muhammad apparently studied with Jews and apparently some of his sayings correspond with midrashim. So perhaps there is still a lost midrash out there which was the source of the Qur'anic story? :-)

Answer (score 8):

Since Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, there has been little faith in any philosophical proof of theological and metaphysical claims. But then, despite the misnamed "Kuzari Principle", this is R' Yehudah haLevi's point in much of the first section of the Kuzari as well.

The Kuzari opens with the king having a series of dreams in which an angel tells him, "Your way of thinking pleases G-d, but not your way of acting."

The king believes because of his experience of the Divine, not because of a proof.

Similarly, the chaver tells the king in 1:13: That which you describe is religion based on speculation and system, the research of thought, but open to many doubts. Now ask the philosophers, and you will find that they do not agree on one action or one principle, since some doctrines can be established by arguments, which are only partially satisfactory, and still much less capable of being proved.

And later in their dialog, 1:63: “There is an excuse for the Philosophers. Being Grecians, science and religion did not come to them as inheritances.”

R’ Gil Student posted the following quote from Louis Jacobs, We Have Reason to Believe, pp. 25-26, 28-30 on Hirhurim's article on the [Proofs of God](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2007/04/proofs-of-god.html) :

> Since Kant, these proofs [of God’s existence] have been heavily assailed…. Many theologians, nowadays, accept the validity of these refutations and admit that there can be no proof of God in the sense that there can be no proof of a mathematical formula… But they go on to remark that we can be convinced of a thing beyond of a shadow of a doubt by means other than that of mathematical proof. There is no such proof, for instance, of the existence of other human beings beside ourselves, yet we are convinced that they do exist… In other words a distinction must be drawn between proof and conviction — proof is one of the ways to conviction but there are other ways, too…
>
> Many have arrived at this conviction as the result of a personal experience which convinces them that God exists. These men would rule out of court the very discussion of whether God exists, for, they would say, if a man is truly in love he does not ask himself if he is in love. The experience of God’s Presence is sufficient…
>
> Other thinkers, again, hold that though each of the traditional proofs in itself is unconvincing, taken together they are convincing… Granted that the proofs carry no weight as evidence, they are indications and as such have the power of supplementing each other…
>
> What it all amounts to is this, that while the existence of God cannot be proved if we start from the beginning, none of us do, in fact, start from the beginning. We are presented with two alternative beliefs about the ultimate reality and we have to choose between them. According to one view God exists–it is He Who created us, Who fashioned our minds and implanted the moral sense within us so that we are capable of recognising beauty, truth and goodness and fighting ugliness, falsehood and evil. In this view the difficulty is how to account for the existence of evil. According to the other view there is no God… In this view the difficulties are how mind came from matter, how life emerged where there was no life before, how the universe itself came into being, how the good is possible of realisation and how man came to strive for it–how man as a tiny part of the universe came to pass judgment on it?

Similarly, a more contemporary philosopher [R/Prof Shalom Carmy (of YU)](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol07/v07n087.shtml#07) wrote on Avodah:

> People who throw around big words on these subjects always seem to take for granted things that I don’t.
>
> The people who keep insisting that it’s necessary to prove things about G-d, including His existence, seem to take it for granted that devising these proofs is identical with knowing G-d.
>
> Now if I know a human being personally the last thing I’d do, except as a purely intellectual exercise, is prove his or her existence.

Ever notice how looking at a working hand is so much more compelling of an argument from design than the actual Argument from Design?

I believe because the experience of Shabbos as per the halakhos humans interpreted and legislated from the system He gave us compellingly tells me He's there. I believe because I study His Torah, and the sheer aesthetics of it tells me He's there. I hear Him in my struggles with kashrus and taharas hamishpachah and in the beauty of a flower.

This is why Shabbos is described in the Torah (and Qiddush) as being "between Me and the Children of Israel, a sign forever, that in six days Hashem made heaven and earth, and on the seventh day He 'rested'."

Comment: sounds similar to [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44521/6873) although more thorough.

Answer (score 5):

Intelligent Design is the classic and most powerful argument for the existence of God as scripture says "from my flesh I shall see God" ([Job 19:26](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2719.htm#26))

(see the the treatise [shaar bechina](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=414) of chovos halevavos which delves into this at depth or the book "The Universe Testifies" by Rabbi Avigdor Miller. These works not only address the intelligent design of life forms but also at the structure of the universe as a whole - everything has a function. see there.)

The rise of the random evolution theory last century caused the argument to lose some impact but the tide has been turning.

With the advance of microbiology the argument has become much more powerful as the famous philosopher Anthony Flew, who for many decades flew the flag for atheism and then reversed said:

> "I think that the most impressive arguments for God’s existence are
>   those that are supported by recent scientific discoveries. I’ve never
>   been much impressed by the kalam cosmological argument, and I don’t
>   think it has gotten any stronger recently. However, I think the
>   argument to Intelligent Design is enormously stronger than it was when
>   I first met it."... FLEW: Absolutely. It seems to me that Richard
>   Dawkins constantly overlooks the fact that... the findings of more
>   than fifty years of DNA research have provided materials for a new and
>   enormously powerful argument to design.

[A Change of Mind for Antony Flew](http://www.arn.org/docs/williams/pw_antonyflew.htm)

See also the book Nature's Destiny by Michael Denton which shows that the universe itself and the laws of physics, chemistry, biology, geology all appear to be uniquely fit for homo-sapien like life as it exists on earth.

Comment: Related chat room to earlier version of this answer http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9102/discussion-between-double-aa-and-good-ole-ray

Comment: he also ruled out teleological proofs for God (not surprising, because they aren't proofs as discussed above).

Comment: they are not proofs to you but to many other people they are valid proofs as i added in the answer a quote from Flew and which you deleted in my comment.

Comment: they are only valid proofs to people who don't understand what a proof is so I don't see why that is relevant. FTR I deleted the comment as obsolete **AFTER** it had been edited into the answer.

Comment: Why would aliens help the problem? (who designed the aliens?)

Comment: @YEZ An infinite regress.

Comment: Nothing after the first sentence appears to answer the question, which sought Jewish sources. Is the rest of the argument the one that is presented in Bereishit Rabbah?

Comment: @ray Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus_argument That isn't saying any infinite regress is illogical.

Answer (score 3):

Here a few of the proofs I collected a few a years ago (all from major scientists and professors by the way)

- There is an accepted understanding in science: anything with a probability of under 1/(10^50) is impossible and will never happen. Scientists compare it to someone trying to select a specific crystal of sand from a sandbox the size of the earth. This rule is one that is accepted in all universities, labs, and facilities. However, Dr. Carl Sagan was once asked what the odds that the world was created through natural mutations? He answered “1/102,000,000,000.” Thus, he confirmed that the world must have had been created by a Creator. This doesn't mean that anything with a probability of more than 1/(10^50) are likely to have occurred, because numbers such as 1/(10^30) still takes a tremendous leap of faith to embrace.
  Each of the thousands of different proteins in nature is a chain of 20 different amino acids. Their sequential order is crucial; if they are arranged properly the chain folds and becomes a 3D molecule. However, if they are assembled incorrectly no protein will form. Scientist Douglass Axe published in the JBM that the possibility of a protein being formed by random mutation is (10^74) or 
  1:100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000. Keeping in mind, there is a time limitation from the Cambrian explosion. Also keeping in mind, that there are only (10^65) atoms in the entire galaxy. A parable is given to the probability of this random mutation: a blindfolded man standing in space attempting to locate a single atom. According to the first rule that we stated, that anything over 1/(10^50) is impossible, which is accepted by science; we see here that it is impossible for a protein to be formed through random mutation, therefore proving existence of a creator to form the protein.
- If one took a ruler that stretched 14 billion light-years - the approximate size of the universe (it could be much larger) [while keeping in mind the laws and principals of physics (gravity- F=GmM/R2)] and alternated the ruler out of the exact space of gravity in the universe, nothing over the size of a pea would be able to exist. In other words, organisms such as bacteria could be  exist, however anything to a certain extent larger than that would not be able to live.

Of course, I have many stored in my computer somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. "1065 atoms in the entire galaxy" "1/1050 is impossible" "alternated the ruler out of the exact space of gravity in the universe"???? Also, you negate the anthropic principle.

Comment: @DoubleAA 10 to the 65th power and 10 to the 50th power. When I copied and pasted it didn't come out well.

Comment: @DoubleAA and you can also apply all the answers to the question about the truth of Judaism to this question as well.

Comment: What's the ruler doing exactly? Also do you plan on addressing the anthropic principle? Otherwise your first point is kinda useless.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYnZzE_fADU

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm going to be BN fix this later it needs work.

Comment: Throw 4 dices on a table, you get 4 numbers. the chance of getting that specific set of numbers is 1/1296. You just made something with chances 1/1296 happen in reality.

Comment: @shoosh I think he means 1/10^50, in which case you would need about 65 dice to make your point. Still a good point though.

Comment: @DoubleAA see the video Case for a Creator.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I like your idea, but I have a few questions: 1) What do you mean by "a protein formed through random mutation"? You mean genetic mutation or random combination? 2) What is the hypothetical ruler trying to prove? 3)What is stored on your computer?

Comment: Einstein supposedly said "time is infinite, my lifespan is finite. what are the chances that i am here today? Zero. but you don't ask probabilities after the fact". I am not saying chance is enough to explain life, just playing devil's advocate

Comment: I think Carl Sagan would be rolling in his grave after this answer!

Comment: Well, I'm kinda rolling on my floor at all the numbers being thrown about randomly here. Some of them can be fixed and some not.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define who "we" is in your question. But how do *prophets* know that G-d exists? - Answer: They speak with him! According to the gemara in Megillah, there were hundreds of thousands of prophets in our history. The question is always about the rest of us, but don't forget them.
There is also something called "רוח הקודש". Even non-prophets who are spiritually sensitive enough have some kind of "sensory" evidence; some contact with the divine. Again, the question is only for the rest of us.
When there was a Beis Hamikdash and shechinah, there were miracles and spiritual connection that everyone could see. Your question is only for those of us who missed all that.
[Chazal](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.75a.4?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) also say, from Devarim 4:6,

> אָמַר רַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָנִי אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן: מִנַּיִן
> שֶׁמִּצְוָה עַל הָאָדָם לְחַשֵּׁב תְּקוּפוֹת וּמַזָּלוֹת —
> שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וּשְׁמַרְתֶּם וַעֲשִׂיתֶם כִּי הִיא חׇכְמַתְכֶם
> וּבִינַתְכֶם לְעֵינֵי הָעַמִּים״, אֵיזוֹ חָכְמָה וּבִינָה שֶׁהִיא
> לְעֵינֵי הָעַמִּים — הֱוֵי אוֹמֵר: זֶה חִישּׁוּב תְּקוּפוֹת
> וּמַזָּלוֹת.
> What wisdom and understanding is there in the Torah that is in the
> eyes of the nations, i.e., appreciated and recognized by all? You must
> say: This is the calculation of astronomical seasons and the movement
> of constellations, as the calculation of
> experts is witnessed by all.
>
> Rashi:
> לעיני העמים - שחכמה הניכרת היא שמראה להם סימן לדבריו בהילוך החמה
> והמזלו' שמעידין כדבריו שאומר שנה זו גשומה והיא כן שנה זו שחונה והיא כן
> It was a wisdom that was recognizable, for
> it showed them evidence from knowledge of astronomy; they could say,
> "This year will be sunnier, this year will be rainier" - and it would
> be.

They could predict the weather more accurately than anyone else, and the nations recognized it.
There was a time when we understood the Torah so deeply that the secrets of the physical creation were known by Torah scholars, more deeply than by anyone else. *Everyone*, even non-Jews, could tell that they had a connection to reality that no one else could match. - So this question only applies in our days, when we don't know that much Torah either.
[Note that a lot of this is equivalent to answers to "How do I know that the Torah is true" types of questions.]
People fuss a lot about the "Kuzari argument" about the event at Har Sinai, but this was also a Kuzari argument. He talks about super-humans, and the next step as well: evidence for the rest of us coming from knowing about the existence of these type of super-humans and super-places and their super-powers and super-knowledge.
People talk about how "If we knew ____ for sure, we wouldn't have free will!" But that skips the idea that we had plenty of free will in the old days too. It was just on a different topic. That was the real world; that was how it was supposed to be, and will be again.
It's hard living in the world of hester panim, where it seems that much of what we have to go on just looks like stories to most people.  I honestly believe that you can't blame anyone too much for not believing in our days; this is a world of confusion. Fortunate are those who have had better ways of knowing the truth.

Comment: "_How do prophets know that G-d exists? - They speak with him!_" How do they know it is G-d speaking with them?

Comment: @TamirEvan see Derech Hashem part 3, and this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/132557/31534

Comment: @TamirEvan Rabbi Kaii brought a good answer. But truth is I don't understand the question. Here we were asked, How do we know that God exists? No one asks, How do we know that my computer or my sandwich exists? Well, maybe Descartes, but that's a whole different type of question. The point of the problem given was that we don't have data or perception of God. The prophets did.

Comment: @MichoelR You say "no one asks" but I actually opened my answer above with "Assuming we all exist, think, know and interact with our actual surroundings etc." for a reason.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're right, but I'm right too, as you said with "Assuming..." Mostly we aren't asking Descartes' question. We just want to know that what we believe is reasonably based on the facts.

Comment: Writeup in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VPf_6eyop6ZWr5n7FZ900ACNS9e3ZpHP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for traditional sources, and nobody has brought this (although the point is often reckoned as the teleological argument, which has been covered, I hope to take it a step further B'EH), I will bring [Chovot Ha-Levavot, book 6, chapter 16](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_First_Treatise_on_Unity.6.16?ven=Duties_of_the_Heart,_trans._Rabbi_Yosef_Sebag).

In it, he writes:

> והלא תראה אם ישפך לאדם דיו פתאום על נייר חלק שא״‎א שיצטייר ממנו עליו
> כתב מסודר ושיטות נקראות כמו שיהיה בקולמוס. ואלו הביא אדם לפנינו כתב
> מסודר ממה שאי אפשר להיות מבלי מצוע קולמוס ואומר כי נשפך הדיו על הנייר
> ונעשתה צורת הכתב עליו מעצמה היינו ממהרים להכזיבו על פניו שאיננו נמלט
> מכוונת מכוין
>
> Behold and see, that if a man suddenly pours ink on clean paper, it
> would be impossible for there to be drawn on it orderly writing and
> legible lines like it would be with a pen, and if a man brought before
> us orderly writing from what cannot be written without use of a pen,
> and he would say that ink was spilled on paper, and the form of the
> writing happened on its own, we would be quick to call him a liar to
> his face. For we would feel certain that it could not have happened
> without an intelligent person's intent.

The teleological argument, as brought by DoubleAA, is that the universe is too complex to be an accident. The fine-tuning that went into the universe is so exactly crafted for life, moral life, that many have claimed this proof of God. However, there are good responses (such as the [anthropic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle)), so let's look closer at Rabbeinu Bachaye's words and see why he is so confident in them.

He's actually subtly making a second point, other than the first point (that the world is too complicated to be an accident).

> שאיננו נמלט מכוונת מכוין
>
> We cannot escape from there being someone who intended this.

Why not? It's not *just* that the ink spilled in a way that appears intentional. The *fact that the ink spilled in the first place* must have been intentional!

---

> *In the beginning, there was just a bottle of ink. Then it spilled.*

Difficulty! If there was *just* a bottle of ink, how/why did it spill?
-*Maybe the wind blew it?*
Difficulty! There was no wind, just a bottle of ink.
-*Maybe it got hot and the bottle cracked?*
Difficulty! There was no external source of heat, just a bottle of ink
-*Maybe the glass simply eroded after enough time passed*
Difficulty! There was no time, just a bottle of ink.
-*It spilled מכוונת מכוין*, *because it is not an "it"*; `He wanted to. He had an intent.`
שְׁמַע מִינַּהּ, conclude from it that this explanation is correct.

---

Chovot Levavot goes on to state that this argument refutes the *אנשי הקדמות*, the people who hold the universe is eternal. The teleological argument alone is even less sufficient for that than it is for non-eternal arguments, but the concept that there can't just be **one** single root of multiplicity, unless that one is One, may He be blessed, does. From there onwards - which is beyond the scope of the question - I refer the reader to Jewish theology. Perhaps a good *introduction* is the first chapter of Derech Hashem.

Answer (score 0):

To put it extremely simple, we don't know (That's why we believe), and as humans we will never know, until we pass away.

Everyone can come with very convincing ways to prove g-d though it can easily be refuted as higher power under g-d not g-d.

and others will bring parables or irrefutable proof of him, and it's only to be refuted by the next person, in one to two years or one to two hundred years.

Some believe the 4 letter name yud hey vav Kay, to be g-d when in reality according to Kabbala it's not.

According to kabbala, we are to imagine the above letters in our mind, though ***OUR*** hearts must be with the Eyn Sof (We pray to the eyn sof) the (***Infinite***) Now we all know that infinite is not a body nor a power, it just is and it is Truth, it's ***never*** wrong.

A very interesting thing to know you don't have to be jewish to pray the way a jew prays, you can picture the name, direct your heart accordingly, and just talk, talk to it with concentration, with devotion, with power, with love and ***HONESTLY***.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is the "cosmological" argument of King David in Tehilim 19:1-4, where creation itself "bears witness" to the existence of G_d:

> The heavens are telling of the glory of G_d

I'll admit it now, I am biased in my belief that the traditional scriptures (i.e., the 24 books of the Hebrew Bible) trump any and every other source of traditional authority.

To be sure, virtually every other traditional source of authority has good and helpful things to offer, and those who are familiar with such sources should always feel free to mine them for nuggets of truth that can benefit both them and the larger community of faith (and even the community of non-faith!).

There is a hierarchy, as it were, of authority, and God's Word trumps all other authorities.

Comment: This does not address the question, which asks specifically for answers "According to the sources."

Comment: Hi rhetorician.  It seems like more of this answer is about unbelievers than about belief; could you try to focus this more on the question that was asked?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi again.  This question is attracting a lot of answers that don't directly address the question, which asks what Jewish sources say on this topic. Without that restriction answers become too open-ended and subjective, not what we're looking for. I'm going to delete this. If you decide to [edit] it to bring it into line with the comments you've received, please flag so a moderator can take a look. Thanks.  Sorry about the run-around since I know you came here in the first place because I mentioned Mi Yodeya.

Comment: I'm undeleting this with some rather substantial edits.  Please see the [revision history](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/29739/revisions) for comments.  I know that this isn't as eloquent as your first draft, but it's more focused on answering the question.

Comment: That's fine with me.  I basically said what I wanted to say, and if in doing so I influenced only one person to think there might be a scintilla of truth in what I said about God's Word being believers' primary authority, then I will consider my efforts to have been amply rewarded.  Best wishes, Monica.  Don, rhetorician.

Answer (score -1):

Rambam Hilchos Yesodei Hatorah Chapter 1

Halacha 5
This entity is the God of the world and the Lord of the entire earth. He controls the sphere with infinite and unbounded power. This power [continues] without interruption, because the sphere is constantly revolving, and it is impossible for it to revolve without someone causing it to revolve. [That one is] He, blessed be He, who causes it to revolve without a hand or any [other] corporeal dimension.

Comment: Why not? And let's also recall the Rambam didn't know about friction or gravity.

Comment: @DoubleAA What do you mean I am quoting the Rambam.

Comment: I agreed you are quoting the Rambam...

Comment: FWIW the [celestial spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_spheres) He is allegedly spinning constantly don't actually exist.

Answer (score -2):

It is obvious. How else could such a world come to existence?

---

Not speaking the fact that (at very least) 600.000 men witnessed the miracles on exiting Egypt, crossing the sea, hearing Gcd and getting Thora at the Mount Sinai, eating the *mann* forty years in the desert...

Not entering in detail that, precisely *this* could be the *mitsva*: to be realist, and admit the truth.

ניכרין דברי אמת.

Comment: Saying that 600k people saw something isn't proof because you would have to prove that 600k did see something. Additionally you need to elaborate on what you mean by the world coming into existence (the world as we know it or existence itself). Additionally you need to elaborate on why this world cannot come into existence (first cause arguement or intelligent design I assume).

Comment: @Orion This is the principle of witnessing, that is widely admitted in societies and courts. And once a year, Jewish fathers tell their children the story of exiting Egypt. So we have a chain of witnesses "Our fathers told us that their told them that ... until 600k ocular male major witnesses.".

Comment: -1 If you assume that the OP knows the same facts and still is not convinced, it wouldn't help to insist on them.

Comment: @AlBerko ?? You did not understand the answer.

Comment: Maybe, please explain. Saying "that's obvious" never answers a question. It is not obvious to me, for example, and I know all the facts you listed.

Comment: @AlBerko Ok. Explaination. This post wasn't to say "Your question is bad". It is a *complete* response. But, a very short one. And *here* is the essence of the answer. The answer is "that this answer is/has to be obvious".

Comment: This question is a very special one. Its answer doesn't reside in 'rational and arguments' space, but in 'admit truth' space. When you think about this question, you arrive at a point where, deeply, you *know* that the answer is, obviously, yes : just see this wonderful world (please, go read some good astronomy/anatomy/mathematics/zoology book for example). But, you can choose to deviate and try to get some arguments that, "yes, maybe, indeed, all this was created by some hazard, all this organization evoluted from a big explosion [that itself came from what?...] " or other crazinesses.

Comment: You maybe know superficially the facts, but you didn't know that the path to the answer is the straight line one - the 'obvious' one. [Even, okay, it could take years to finally understand-admit that is was indeed so evident.] So, in place of embarking on building in your brain some nonsense, please stop and listen in your heart to this 'obvious' truth.

Comment: You can read this "obvious" in the sense of 'straight'. In the sense of 'in a big demonstration you can arrive nowhere and lose good sense" - stop.

Comment: Or, to reuse your words: the first part of the answer didn't try to "convince". But to say, 'stop digging in coal mines, just raise your head and look at the sun'.

Answer (score -4):

Written Torah is essentially the proof of God existence. Science (Big Bang) also confirms that all came out of 1 source. Thus there is God and there is only 1 real God. Other gods are not real.

Comment: Also, "Game of thrones" is the proof that dragons exist.

Comment: how is the written torah proof of God?

Comment: @m.r. It just is. It explains who God is, what He wants and what is going on. Read it and see for yourself.What kind of proof you have expected? There was also a pillar of smoke/fire over Tabernacle but until it is rebuilt it is not going to appear, so Written Torah is the only existing true proof.

Comment: @Aleksandr Sigalov Do you understand what proof is? if I show you a book talking about about how a purple demon God with 4 arms created the world  and what he wants with it, its not proof that this thing exists. For the torah to be proof you must prove the Torah is true.

Comment: @Orion the question didn't ask to prove the Torah was true, t just asked on what "traditional Jewish source" should people believe in G-d, if you don't believe in that source, that's a different question