# How do you know Judaism is true?

Tags: theology

there are many religions out there, each with its own framework of beliefs/premises about God (or something else.)

How do you know the Jewish perspective is the correct one?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/how-do-we-know-that-god-exists don't we have a duplicate of this somewhere?

Comment: You dont! If it was so simple there would be no b'chira.

Comment: @annex http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=1&halocha=1&hilite=

Comment: http://www.torahanytime.com/video/sign-language-the-truth-of-judaism-my-conversation-with-hollywood/