# Why do we believe that God is all powerful?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, creation

The only way we could know that God is all powerful is if we knew that He created the universe — then, logically, He would be all-powerful within it. (And, to the best of our knowledge, nothing exists outside of the universe asides from Him.) But the only way we actually know that God created the universe is because He told us so. What if He was lying? And nothing actually created the universe, and God is just the *most*-powerful force, but not actually *all*-powerful?

Comment: Why is that logically true

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38376/759