# Proof of Hashem via Talmud/Amora/Tanna

Tags: talmud-gemara, hashkafah-philosophy, theology

Does anyone know of the places where a Tanna/Amora offers a proof for the existence of Hashem.

ie: Bereshit Rabbah 39:1 Avraham Avinu passes a castle on fire (see below)

Is there perhaps a list, or a source that might contain a list of such discussions/proofs?

To be clear - I would like only Tanna/Amaroic proofs/sources.

---

Sources I have found:

[**Otzar Mirdrashim. Teruma 1:7 (or just 7)**](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31255&st=&pgnum=25&hilite=)

> ומעשה שבא מין ואמר לר׳ עקיבא, העוה״ז מי בראו? א״ל, הקב״ה. א״ל, הראיני
> דבר ברור. א״ל, למחר תבא אלי. למחר בא אצלו, א״ל מה אתה לובש? א״ל, בגד.
> א״ל, מי עשאו? א״ל, האורג. א״ל, איני מאמינך הראיני דבר ברור. א״ל, ומה
> אראה לך ואין אתה יודע שהאורג עשאו. א״ל, ואתה אינך יודע שהקב״ה ברא את
> עולמו. נפטר אותו המין, אמרו לו תלמידיו מה הדבר ברור? א״ל, בניי כשם
> שהבית מודיע על הבנאי והבגד מודיע על האורג והדלת על הנגר, כך העולם
> מודיע על הקב״ה שהוא בראו, ישתבח ויתעלה שמו לעד ולנצח נצחים, אמן ואמן
> נצח סלה ועד.

[**Bereshit Rabbah 39:1**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22383&st=&pgnum=94)

> וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל אַבְרָם לֶךְ לְךָ מֵאַרְצְךָ וגו' (בראשית יב, א),
> רַבִּי יִצְחָק פָּתַח (תהלים מה, יא): שִׁמְעִי בַת וּרְאִי וְהַטִּי
> אָזְנֵךְ וְשִׁכְחִי עַמֵּךְ וּבֵית אָבִיךְ, אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק
> מָשָׁל לְאֶחָד שֶׁהָיָה עוֹבֵר מִמָּקוֹם לְמָקוֹם, וְרָאָה בִּירָה
> אַחַת דּוֹלֶקֶת, אָמַר תֹּאמַר שֶׁהַבִּירָה הַזּוֹ בְּלֹא מַנְהִיג,
> הֵצִיץ עָלָיו בַּעַל הַבִּירָה, אָמַר לוֹ אֲנִי הוּא בַּעַל הַבִּירָה.
> כָּךְ לְפִי שֶׁהָיָה אָבִינוּ אַבְרָהָם אוֹמֵר תֹּאמַר שֶׁהָעוֹלָם
> הַזֶּה בְּלֹא מַנְהִיג, הֵצִיץ עָלָיו הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וְאָמַר
> לוֹ אֲנִי הוּא בַּעַל הָעוֹלָם. (תהלים מה, יב): וְיִתְאָו הַמֶּלֶךְ
> יָפְיֵךְ כִּי הוּא אֲדֹנַיִךְ. וְיִתְאָו הַמֶּלֶךְ יָפְיֵךְ,
> לְיַפּוֹתֵךְ בָּעוֹלָם, (תהלים מה, יב): וְהִשְׁתַּחֲוִי לוֹ, הֱוֵי
> וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל אַבְרָם.

See end of 38 there for famous argument between Avraham and Nimrod denying polytheism since no physical power seems to have complete control.

**Zohar Lech Lecha 78a:**

> וְרָזָא דְמִלָּה לֶךְ לְךָ דְּהָא קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא יָהִיב לֵיהּ
> לְאַבְרָהָם רוּחָא דְחָכְמְתָא, וְהֲוָה יָדַע וּמְצָרֵף (צנורי)
> סִטְרֵי דְּיִישׁוּבֵי עָלְמָא, וְאִסְתַּכַּל בְּהוּ וְאַתְקַל
> בְּתִיקְלָא וְיָדַע חֵילִין דִּי מְמַנָּן עַל סִטְרֵי יִישׁוּבָא.

**[Midrash Hagadol (Bereishit 12):](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38103&st=&pgnum=123)**

It is very possible this is a combination of the above  sources compiled in the 13th century or perhaps another source we don't have access to. It starts with B"R 38:11 to not serve handmade things, then the Rambam Hilchos Avoda Zara 1:3 since it mentions the sun and moon and not the logic of one destroying the other (ie: B"R 38:11). Then the castle (B"R 39:1) with clothing like Rebbe Akiva (Midrash HaGadol). Or perhaps the Rambam uses this as a source to A"Z 1:3.

> היה משוטט בדעתו ואומר: עד מתי אנו משתחווין למעשה ידינו? אין ראוי לעבוד
> ולהשתחוות אלא לארץ, שהיא מוציאה פירות והיא מחיה אותנו. כיוון שראה,
> שהיא צריכה לגשמים, ואלמלא שמים נפתחים ומורידים גשמים, לא היתה מצמחת
> כלום, חזר ואמר: אין ראוי להשתחוות אלא לשמים. חזר וראה את השמש שהיא
> מאירה לעולם והיא המגדלת צמחים, אמר: ‏אין ראוי להשתחוות אלא לה. כיוון
> שראה אותה שהיא שוקעת, אמר: אין זה אלוה. חזר וראה את הירח ואת הכוכבים,
> שהם מאירין בלילה, אמר: לאלו ראוי להשתחוות. כיוון שעלה עמוד השחר, בטלו
> כולם, אמר: אין אלו אלוה. והיה מצטער ואומר: ‏אלמלא יש להם מנהיג, מפני
> מה זה שוקע וזח עולה?
>
> ‏משל למה הדבר דומה: לאחד שהיה מהלך בדרך וראה בירה גדולה וגבוהה, ביקש
> להיכנס לתוכה, חזר על כל צדדיה ולא מצא פתח, קרא כמה קולות ואין עונה
> אותו. נשא עיניו וראה כלי צמר אדומים, שהם שטוחין על הגג; אחר כך ראה כלי
> פשתן לבנים. אמר אותו האיש: וודאי אדם יש בבירה זו, ואילו לא היה בה אדם,
> למה אלו ניטלין ואלו ניתנין? כיוון שראה אותו בעל הבירה, שהוא מצטער על
> כך, אמר לו: "למח אתה מצטער? אני הוא בעל הבירה!

Comment: There was this question discussing proof of Hashem, and I don't believe that any talmudic sources were quoted, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/how-do-we-know-that-god-exists

Comment: @אילפא yes I did see that and yes it is different because I am not looking for an argument/proof. I am looking for the Tannaic/Amoraic approach I suppose.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.39a.8?lang=he&with=all

Comment: @שלום I am not sure what you are referencing or what the proof is there? I tried going through 38b and 39a and didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: I’m not sure if that’s what you’re looking for, but it’s a proof that man has only one creator

Comment: @שלום I see. More of a proof against idolatry/polytheism. Thanks. Not quite what I am looking for, but still interesting. I appreciate that.